# How can I train a Tensorflow model based on partial objects? (book cover + book edge)

Tags: tensorflow

I would be interested in being able to detect books by pointing a phone camera towards their cover. I found several Tensorflow models matching that requirement. However, in my case, I also sometimes know what the edge of the book associated with that cover looks like, which can be a benefit in the case where 2 books have the same cover but a different edge.

How can I benefit from this additional information to detect book covers in a more precise way, especially when the camera's field of view includes part of the cover and part of the book edge?

Comment: Hi Bruno! If it is about classifying the books on genres , titles and genres of books will only matter. This Use case will be more like text classification. Once you get titles using OCR (Optical Character recognition) , That text and corresponding labels will be trained. Could you clarify your use case  ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TensorflowSupport . I will add an example hereafter. This is the cover of a comic book: https://res.cloudinary.com/dl7hskxab/image/upload/v1623338718/inducks-covers/webusers/webusers/2021/08/de_ltb_549a_001.jpg and this is the image of the corresponding edge of this book: https://edges.ducksmanager.net/edges/de/gen/LTB.549.png , which I sometimes have as well depending on the book. I would like to use the extra information brought by the image of the edge to detect more accurately what comic book the user is pointing at with his camera.

Comment: Hi @Bruno! Sorry for the late response. Generative Adversial networks will be a good candiate for this problem statement . It can create full images from partial images after training . Attached relevant threads for reference. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan